# Get value of placeholder in empty input field with jquery?

Tags: jquery, user-input, placeholder

Something is weird and I'm stumped.

When I have an input field with placeholder, eg:

```
<input id="box1" placeholder="not applicable">
```

I've always been able to grab the user input, or if input is left **empty**, the placeholder value with jquery as such:

```
var text = $('#box1').val();
```

No big deal. using jquery `.val()` always did the trick. Then I started seeing some code output errors in previously working apps wherein empty inputs were not capturing the placeholder value.

Did something change with the javascript engine that would account for this? Or is there a new way to get the placeholder value if the input field is empty?

See this example:

```js
$('#done').on('click', function(){
   if($('#box3').val() == ''){
            var box3 = $(this).data('placeholder');
        } else {
        var box3 = $('#box3').val();
        }
  $('#output').val(box3);
});

// Clicking the button doesn't capture the placeholder value if empty?
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="box3" placeholder="not applicable">
<br><br>
<button id="done">
Done
</button>
<br><br>
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
<br><br>
<p>
Why doesn't the button click capture the value of the placeholder in this instance, using jquery 3.1.1?
</p>
```

Comment: You *want* to get the placeholder text if the value is blank?  From my experience, most browsers don't return the placeholder value if it's empty, aside from IE.  I only remember this because we had to explicitly ignore the placeholder in some of my apps because some users used IE and it send the placeholder text on submit.

Comment: Also placeholder isn't a `data` field, it's an `attr`.

Comment: yes, I want to get the placeholder if value is empty, to improve UI function. It serves as a nice default value if user doesn't need to specify or update. I could set default value with `value=`, but then the user has to go through the trouble of deleting input and re-entering. Placeholder lets you focus and enter immediately.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. I've updated my comment. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `attr('placeholder')`. Also, your use of `this` inside the `if` statement was faulty. It referred to the subject of the `click` function.

```js
$('#done').on('click', function(){
   if($('#box3').val() == ''){
            var box3 = $('#box3').attr('placeholder');
        } else {
           var box3 = $('#box3').val();
        }
  $('#output').val(box3);
});

// Clicking the button doesn't capture the placeholder value if empty?
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="box3" placeholder="not applicable">
<br><br>
<button id="done">
Done
</button>
<br><br>
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
<br><br>
<p>
Why doesn't the button click capture the value of the placeholder in this instance, using jquery 3.1.1?
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. But, I've never had to take this step on many jquery based apps I've written (as a hobbyist coder at least). I've used chrome, FF and IE with the same effect just using `val()`! What gives?

Comment: Was it always with jQuery 3? Maybe the method was updated.